# "As it turned out" vs "it turned out"

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between the two? Example:

> Everyone thought it was a panther. **As it turned out**, that was precisely the case.
>
> Everyone thought it was a panther. **It turned out**, that was precisely the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax is significantly different. The comma is completely wrong in the second version, because *it turned out **that** [something happened/was true]* actually *requires* "that" to reference *the fact of something "turning out"*. That mandatory "that" is *additional* to the (optionally deletable) one referencing the statement that turned out to be true.

Consider [about 13,600 results in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20turned%20out%20that%20that%20was%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) where *both* "that"'s occur consecutively...

> 1: *He didn't expect to die. But [it turned out **that that** was](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20turned%20out%20that%20that%20was%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) what happened.*

If we introduce ***as***, the comma (pause in speech) is required, and the first ***that*** is no longer valid...

> 2: *He didn't expect to die. But **as** it turned out**,** **that** was what happened.*

Note that in common parlance, "it" in #2 may be replaced by other more specific nouns *(things, events, etc.)*, but this would be at least "unusual" in context #1.

---

Apart from the syntactic differences, I don't believe there's any reason to make any *semantic* distinction between the two constructions. They're both relatively informal usages, and it's implicit in *it turned out* that whatever *did* take place or become apparent wasn't what the speaker had expected. But neither version implies any more or less surprise at the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

The two mean exactly the same thing, but "as it turned out" has a bit more of an astonished mood, like they're saying "amazingly, that was precisely the case!"

Answer (score 0):

They're almost identical in sense and meaning.  The only real difference is that "As it turned out" has a slightly stronger hint of *surprise*.  If you say "As it turned out, X." you're saying that X is a somewhat surprising outcome.

"I wondered which teacher I would have for grade 7.  It turned out to be Mrs. Smith, who often taught grade 7."

"I wondered which teacher I would have for grade 7.  As it turned out, both of our usual grade 7 teachers had quit, so they hired someone completely new."

"I wondered which teacher I would have for grade 7.  As it turned out, I had my own father."

It can also be used very sarcastically, in cases where X is not a surprising outcome, but someone has behaved as though they didn't expect it anyway - such as if they act without regard for obvious consequences:

"Did you hear what happened to Jimmy?"

"No!  What happened?"

"As it turns out, the police don't like getting prank calls." (Implication: (1) Jimmy has been making prank calls to the police, (2) Jimmy got in trouble because of it, (3) *no one should be surprised by this outcome*, and yet (4) Jimmy clearly didn't anticipate this outcome, or he wouldn't have done it.)

For this sarcastic usage, you'll use the present tense, since you're making an observation about a general truth that was *illustrated* by these events, rather than making a comment about the events themselves.

"It turns/turned out" can be used in both of these cases instead of "As it turns/turned out", but "As it turns/turned out" emphasizes the surprise in the first case, and the sarcasm in the second case.